# Add Windows Phone platform support to existing C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, arm

I have an opes-source project which I want to use on Windows Phone. Currently it targets one of the following: `Any CPU`, `x86` or `x64`. Apparently, when I build and try to use the output as a reference in a Windows Phone project, I'm getting an error: `A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project`.

I'm trying to build that open-source project so that it would target Windows Phone platform. To achieve that, I'm trying to find a way to add Windows Phone platform somewhere in VS project's settings, but with no luck. Is it possible at all? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of `Windows Phone` do you need to support exactly?  You have install the Windows Phone 8 SDK right?  This is required to target `Windows Phone 8` within Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Windows Phone 8, and yes, I have all the SDKs and related installed.